# New log file every time we uploaded new binaries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, logging

We would like to add some "start code" to indicate log file for every time we update ASP.NET site's binaries. So, for instance, we have binaries ver.1.0, and log writes to log_JhdsgGd1.txt. Next time we correct some bugs and then uploaded new binaries ver.1.1. And now, we want log file writes to some other log_h12jh3G.txt. We don't change any version number in project.

I have tried generate some start code once at Application_Start() and then use it in class that writes log. But unfortunately it doesn't work as supposed to be.

---

POST UPDATE

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Application["startCode"] = r.Next(100000).ToString();

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static class Logger
{
    static internal void WriteLog(string msg, string dbname = null)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("log"), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, String.Format("log_{0}.txt", HttpContext.Current.Application["startCode"]), true)))
        {
            string logEntry;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbname))
                logEntry = String.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), dbname, msg);
            else
                logEntry = String.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), msg);

            sw.WriteLine(logEntry);
            sw.WriteLine("------------");
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Please look at updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you link SVN/GIT revision to your project? Or calculate MD5 of your binary file

Comment: Calculating MD5 from binary seems very interesting way.

Comment: Could you please provide me some sample on that?

Comment: I don't think that you need smth extraordinary, so simple MD5 hash is OK: `string filename = "myfile.exe";

        MD5 md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();

        string md5 = Common.EncodeHex(md5.ComputeHash(File.OpenRead(filename)));`
Common.EncodeHex() is method to encode byte[] ar string, you could use your own

Comment: Better not :) In this case you will not know when file was changed

Comment: What about adding md5 code computation in `Application_Start()`?